# Is it possible to process a full tiled tiff image by saving only one tile in memory every time?

Tags: c++, c, out-of-memory, tiff, libtiff

I'am having a simple issue. I process tiff images that are enormous (>4GB), and when loading all of them in memory i fill my RAM and the program is killed. I tried to save them as tiled tiffs and then use libtiff to load them tile-by-tile like this:

```
tdata_t buf = _TIFFmalloc(TIFFTileSize(tifSrc));
for(int i = 0;i< 20000;i+=128){
        for(int j = 0;j< 20000;j+=128)
        {
                TIFFReadTile(tifSrc, buf , i, j, 0,0);
                TIFFWriteTile(tifDst, (tdata_t)buf , i, j,0, 0);
        }
}
_TIFFfree(buf);
```

But althought i expected the above code to load in memory only one tile per iteration (128x128 bytes), the whole image is stored instead...
Does anybody know how can i load only one tile in memory?

Comment: buf, it was just a typo...Thanks!

Comment: Is the TIFF actually tiled? My understanding is that the TIFF format does not require the file to be internally stored as tiles. Wiki seems to indicate that's actually [an extension to the format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Tiles).

Comment: Yeap, it is...When i use the TIFFTileSize(tifSrc) above..it does return "49152" which is 128x128x3, which is what i am expecting from  a 128x128 tile...

Comment: I don’t see why this would store the whole file in memory. You allocate space for only one tile. Where would the rest go? You must be doing something else elsewhere in your code that you are not showing. Consider creating a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

To answer my own question, you must first assign the tags TIFFTAG_TILEWIDTH and TIFFTAG_TILELENGTH like this:

```
TIFFSetField(tiff, TIFFTAG_TILEWIDTH, (uint32)128);
TIFFSetField(tiff, TIFFTAG_TILELENGTH, (uint32)128);
```

Then the read and write functions succeed by returning "0", and only the 128x128 tile is loaded into memory!